# Как спарсить с сайта определенные данные?

Tags: python, парсер, pandas

как спарсить с сайта определенные данные, вот у меня есть скрипт который подсчитывает количество онлайна во фракции(это в игре если что), но я хочу сделать что бы он еще подсчитывал кол-во 9 рангов которые находятся в сети, помогите пожалуйста

```
import pandas as pd
fraction = input("Введите номер фракции: ")
url = f"https://arizona-rp.com/mon/fraction/8/{fraction}"
df = pd.read_html(url)[0]
online = df.loc[df[3] == 'Сейчас играет', 1].to_list()
zam = df.loc[df[2] == '9', 1].to_list()
print(f'Фракция {fraction} сейчас играют {len(online)} игроков, из них {len(zam)} заместителей')
```

Comment: А сейчас что не так, неправильно считает?

Comment: Считает правильно, но оно выводит всех заместителей(9) я нужно что бы выводило только тех кто "Сейчас играет"

Comment: Для начинающих полно таториалов по Pandas на ютьюбе, я сам так учился )

Answer (score 2):

Можно объединять условия побитовыми операциями. И нужно обязательно брать в скобки условия при этом:

```
zam_online = df.loc[(df[3] == 'Сейчас играет') & (df[2] == '9'),1].to_list()
```